# Secure Boot Violation: Invalid Signature Detected, Check Secure Boot Policy in Setup Error - HackBGRT (how to use secure boot with it)

Tags: windows, boot, security, bios, secure-boot

Update - Go to answer for steps.

First off, I am trying to enable secure Boot thus I don't consider disabling secure Boot a solution.

I have a Gigabyte B450M DS3H, with AMD Ryzen 5600 and have tried enabling secure Boot through the bios.

Is there any way to fix this without reinstalling Windows?

My steps were:
-Disable CSM
-Enable Secure Boot
-Restore Factory Keys
-Save and Reset

When I boot, Windows says secure Boot is enabled, but the bios shows an error at Boot which is the title of the question. The bios allows me to close this error and continue the boot though.

I also tried to "Enroll EFI Image" by selecting C:\Windows\Boot\EFI\bootmgfw.efi but then it did not secure boot and windows entered an "automatic repair".

For reference, Windows 11 was clean installed (not upgraded from Win 10) before trying to enable secure Boot. AMD fTPM (TPM V2.0) was already enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I ended up figuring out the problem, it was because I had configured HackBGRT onto the system.

In the end, here was the problem and the resolution.

In order:

I built the PC from scratch and enabled fTPM in BIOS (secure boot NOT enabled)

I clean installed Win 11 Pro (Production) from a USB Boot Drive

I set up a custom bios image with HackBGRT

I then tried to enable secure boot - which worked BUT, the bios gave a dismissable error every time the PC booted which is in the title

Once it booted Windows said Secure Boot was Enabled

In the end the resolution was:
In the GIGABYTE BIOS, I went to Secure Boot --> Key Management (under custom) --> Enroll EFI Image and then I selected the Windows Filesystem and the bootx64.efi file in the HackBGRT Folder, save and reset and problem solved.

NOTE: I am not sure if this is possible if your bios does not support the "enroll efi image" function or equivalent, also this may be named differently in other vendor's bioses.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. Great that you resolved it :-) When a solution is found, one doesn't signify it in same way as one would in discussion forums with a note in title or the question. Instead you simply [accept](https://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer) the helpful answer - and yes, you can (and should) accept your own too, tho' you have to wait for 48 hours to accept one of your own. It's a good idea to take the [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour) and check the Asking and Answering -sections in the [Help](https://superuser.com/help) to learn how these sites work.

Answer (score 0):

If you had Windows 11 running without Secure Boot, then for sure it was Windows 11 Insider or the flag to permit Windows 11 had be set. Somehow the flag to run without all the Production features was set.

To install Production Windows 11, you will have to make sure UEFI, Secure Boot and TPM V2 are all properly enabled and set up and then Install Production Windows fresh.

Back up data first on a USB drive.

Based on your comments, you probably should update BIOS (UEFI) before reinstalling.

Comment: I don't believe so, its a production version of Windows 11 Pro and it was clean installed when I built the PC (not from Win 10). TPM and UEFI were already enabled, just not secure boot.

Comment: Windows 11 Production will not run without Secure Boot enabled. You  got an error trying to enable Secure Boot. So I am fairly sure the flag to run with Secure Boot got set and that does mean now a fresh install.

Comment: the error is on the BIOS side, not OS side, the bios says to change the key policy in it's setup, and windows still boots just fine, the only difference noticeable is in the windows security app, where it states secure boot enabled (when its on but BIOS produces dismissable error message at startup) or it dosen't mention secure boot when I disable it (and it still boots normally).

Comment: Something screwy because Windows 11 Production must have Secure Boot enabled. You might trying updating Bios to ensure it is working correctly

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that one as well, the BIOS was at the latest version before attempting to enable Secure Boot

Comment: You will need to install Windows 11 Pro fresh as I have said.